# Incluir mais uma condicao para executar Script

Tags: script, condição

```
 $outracondicao = 'S';

    $script = new TElement('script'); 
    $script->type = 'text/javascript'; 
    $script->add("$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]class=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if('".__CLASS__."' == results[1])  
    __adianti_load_page('engine.php?class=AtendimentosEmProcessoList&method=onReload');
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: Como acrescente ao que foi já dito, não faça questões que apenas tem código e não descrição detalhada do problema. Para além disso faltou incluir a tag de linguagem apropriada, quer seja aparenta ser php

Comment: Desculpe pessoal,  Sou novo por aqui.
Tenho  um sistema em PHP com uma datagrid que preciso atualizar automaticamente.   Para isso achei o scritp em javascritp acima que funciona muito bem.   Porem nessa grid tenho um botao que abre uma janela TWindow   e como o settimer continua ligado acaba fechando minha janela Twindow.    Por isso preciso colocar no script mais uma condição para ele executar.  Obrigado.